# SQL update strange query

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hi I have to unite few rows in one table in mssql db.

```
update rashod
  set kol = (select sum(r.kol) from rashod r inner join rashod r1 on r1.k_tovar=r.k_tovar      
  where r.idnak = 2935691 and r.k_tovar=r1.k_tovar), 
    summa = (select sum(r2.summa) from rashod r2 inner join rashod r3 on r2.k_tovar=r3.k_tovar where r2.idnak = 2935691 and r2.k_tovar=r3.k_tovar)
```

is it a correct query?

in table "rashod" few rows can have the same k_tovar AND idnak. if so -> we unite these rows. column kol `=sum(kol)`, column `summa=sum(summa)`. This new row is kept in db and all old should be removed.
Help please.

Answer (score 0):

please try this

```
update rashod set kol= data.kol_sum,summa=data.sum_summa
 from 
 (
    select sum(r.kol) as kol_sum,sum(r2.summa)as sum_summa,r.k_tovar as k_tovar  from rashod r inner join rashod r1 on r1.k_tovar=r.k_tovar      
    where r.idnak = 2935691
     group by r.k_tovar,r1.k_tovar
)data where rashod.k_tovar=data.k_tovar
```

Comment: so with this statement all records of idnak 2935691 and for all tovars will be updated to have the sums. i think we need an insert here and with a different flag in another column so as to distinguish this newly created sum row from all the others in order to delete them after the insertion

Comment: Something wrong. I had two records in db. kol=3 and kol=5. after this query kol=65024

Comment: try without the inner join inside the parentheses and with extra where at the end of statement 'and rashod.idnak = 2935691' and let us know

Answer (score 0):

this works

```
update rashod set kol= data.kol_sum,summa=data.sum_summa
 from 
 (
    select sum(r.kol) as kol_sum,sum(r.summa)as sum_summa,r.k_tovar as k_tovar  from rashod r   
    where r.idnak = 2935691
     group by r.k_tovar
)data where rashod.k_tovar=data.k_tovar and rashod.idnak = 2935691
```